# How to call object from one class to another in C#

Tags: c#

I have a problem that I just can't solve on my own. I am new to programming and I would appreciate if you could help me with this issue:
I have a class I would like to inherit from:

```
namespace rsDeployer.Common.SQLServerCommunication         
{
    public class RSDatabaseConnectionCreator: LoggerBase
    {
        public RSProfile profile;
        public RSDatabaseConnectionCreator(RSProfile profile)
        {
            this.profile = profile;
        }

        public SqlConnection CreateConnection(RSDatabaseNames DatabaseName, bool UseWindowsAuthentication, bool testConnection = false)
        {
            var connectionString = BuildRSDatabaseConnectionString(DatabaseName, UseWindowsAuthentication);            
            if (testConnection)
            {
                return IsConnectionAvailable(connectionString) ? new SqlConnection(connectionString) : null;
            }
            return new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        }
    }
}
```

and I would like to call CreateConnection() in another class to inject to methods to allow me to open connection and then execute scripts.
Edit 1 - class I would like to have it injected to.

```
        public void QueryExecution(string SQLQuery)
    {

        //here's where I would like to inject it
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(SQLQuery, conn);
        var file = new StreamWriter(@"D:\Project\rsDeployer\ImportedQuery.txt");
        file.WriteLine(command);
        file.Close();
    }
```

If this question is way to silly to deserve answer would you just point in the direction where I should read about it?

I hope this question is well asked and clear.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should search about creating instance of an object.

Comment: can you show how you are expecting to use it? What the consumer class would looks like.

Answer (score 2):

Like this,

```
public void QueryExecution(string SQLQuery)
{ 
    RSProfile profile = new RSProfile();
    RSDatabaseConnectionCreator instance = new RSDatabaseConnectionCreator(profile);
    SqlConnection conn = instance.CreateConnection(...);
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(SQLQuery, conn);
    var file = new StreamWriter(@"D:\Project\rsDeployer\ImportedQuery.txt");
    file.WriteLine(command);
    file.Close();
    conn.Close();
}
```

You also told that you want to inherit from this class, here is another approach,

```
public class RSDatabaseConnectionCreator : LoggerBase
{
    public virtual object CreateConnection() // by virtual you can override it.
    {
      return new object();
    }
}

public class AnotherClass : RSDatabaseConnectionCreator {

    public AnotherClass() {
        CreateConnection(); // by inheriting RSDatabaseConnectionCreator , you can reach public functions.
    }

    public override object CreateConnection() // or you can override it 
    {
        // here might be some user Login check
        return base.CreateConnection(); // then you open connection
    }
}
```

Hope helps,

Comment: Maybe use `using conn = instance.CreateConnection();`, so the Connection will be disposed automatically...

Comment: You are right but, this is just a sample of creating instance of an object :) @MartinVerjans

Answer (score 1):

This is how you do it.  Apologies for a major blunder in the earlier answer. This one has the connection surrounded by a using.

```
 namespace rsDeployer.Common.SQLServerCommunication         
    {
       public class ConsumerClass
       { 
           public void QueryExecution(string SQLQuery)
           {

           var profile = new RsProfile();
           var rsConnectionCreator = new RSDatabaseConnectionCreator(profile);
               using(var sqlConnection = rsConnectionCreator.CreateConnection(...Parameters here...)){
                      SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(SQLQuery, sqlConnection );


                }
                var file = new StreamWriter(@"D:\Project\rsDeployer\ImportedQuery.txt");
                      file.WriteLine(command);
                      file.Close();
           }
       }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe use `using conn = instance.CreateConnection();`, so the Connection will be disposed automatically...

Answer (score 1):

Hope this is what you are requesting for

```
public class ClassX
{
    private RSProfile _rsprofile;
    RSDatabaseConnectionCreator _dbConnectionCreator;
    private SqlConnection _sqlConnection;

        public ClassX()
        {
           _rsProfile = xxx; //  Get the RSProfile object
           _dbConnectionCreator = new RSDatabaseConnectionCreator (_rsProfile);
           RSDatabaseNames databaseName = yyy; //  get the RSDatabaseNames 
           var useWindowsAuthentication = true; 
           var testConnection = false;

          _sqlConnection = _dbConnectionCreator.CreateConnection(databaseName,useWindowsAuthentication ,testConnection );
        }

}
```

Comment: Thank you guys so much, I really appreciate your effort. I got this solved! And I wasn't stomped for my question's syntax (I am so fab:P) ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can inject the connection creator into the consumer class through the constructor.

```
public class Consumer
{
    private RSDatabaseConnectionCreator _connectionCreator;

    // Constructor injection
    public Consumer (RSDatabaseConnectionCreator connectionCreator)
    {
        _connectionCreator = connectionCreator;
    }

    public void QueryExecution(string SQLQuery)
    {
        using (var conn = _connectionCreator.CreateConnection(dbName, true, true)) {
            if (conn != null) {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note: The using statement automatically closes the connection.

Usage

```
var connectionCreator = new RSDatabaseConnectionCreator(profile);
var consumer = new Consumer(connectionCreator);
consumer.QueryExecution(sqlQuery);
```

---

If you want to inject the connection creator at each call of `QueryExecution`, you can inject it directly into the method as an additional parameter, instead.

```
public void QueryExecution(string SQLQuery, RSDatabaseConnectionCreator connectionCreator)
{
    using (var conn = connectionCreator.CreateConnection(dbName, true, true)) {
        if (conn != null) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Usage

```
var connectionCreator = new RSDatabaseConnectionCreator(profile);
var consumer = new Consumer();
consumer.QueryExecution(sqlQuery, connectionCreator);
```